# QUERY_STRING rewrite is not being accounted for

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !embed=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/old-page$ /wiki/new-page [L,R]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/index.php [L]
```

However, when I go to
/wiki/old-page
instead of redirecting to
/wiki/new-page
it redirects to
/wiki/Old-page

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it redirects at all? Because there are no redirections to be seen anywhere in your rules, only internal rewrites. I suggest you tell us _what_ you want to achieve, not _how_ you think you can achieve it.

Comment: I want /wiki/old-page to redirect to /wiki/new-page if embed=true is not in the url. But I think the final line is executing and ignoring the query_string. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The final line certainly is not depending on the condition at the top of the file. Conditions only apply to the next rule, not to all rules. That is documented, you need to read the documentation. But nevertheless there is not redirection defined in those rules you posted. Only internal rewrites. So I do not see why you would expect  redirection to take place.